# Why SearchBar not showing in TabBarController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchbar, uitabbar

I created a `HomeViewController` which includes a search bar. The search bar looks good when my rootViewController is `HomeViewController`. But after I connected `HomeViewController` with a tab in `TabBarController`, my search bar disappears. What should I do if I want it to show only when I touch that tab?

This is what I have in `HomeViewController`:

```
class HomeViewController: UICollectionViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {
    private let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupSearchBar()
        }
    
    private func setupSearchBar(){
        definesPresentationContext = true
        navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        let textFieldInsideSearchBar = searchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
        textFieldInsideSearchBar?.textColor = .black
        textFieldInsideSearchBar?.placeholder = "position"
        ......
    }
}
```

This is what I did in `TabBarController`:

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {
    var homepage: HomeViewController?
    ......

    var subviewController: [UIViewController] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        homepage = HomeViewController()
        ......

        subviewController.append(homepage!)
        ......

        homepage?.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Home", image: UIImage(named: "home"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "home-selected"))
        homepage?.tabBarItem.tag = 1
        ......
        self.setViewControllers(subviewController, animated: true)

        self.selectedIndex = 0
        self.selectedViewController = homepage
    }
}
```

This is what in `SceneDelegate`:

```
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else{return}
            window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
            window?.windowScene = windowScene
            window?.rootViewController =
                    UINavigationController(rootViewController:
                    TabBarController())
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
```

I am a beginner in iOS. Thanks in advance if anyone can help me!

Comment: where is your HomeViewController navigation bar or item? you must have a navigation controller and the rootview controller of navigation controller must be set to Home view controller, and one of your tabbarview must set to the navigationcontroller.

Comment: homepage = HomeViewController(),  let nav = UInavigationController(rootviewcontroller: homepage) ,    subviewController.append(nav!)

Comment: Thank you!  I add `let nav = UInavigationController(rootviewcontroller: homepage) `, `subviewController.append(nav!)`after `homepage = HomeViewController()`. But I got "cannot find UInavigationController in scope...". Could you help me with this?

Comment: And I also have two more ViewController. Do they need navigation controller?

Comment: can you share your app images?